# how to use regex to match this pattern

Tags: java, regex

i want to search following pattern:

```
any_var.add(anything.substring(any))
```

as long is it match with:

```
*.add(*.substring(*))
```

how to do that in regex? Im using java.

Comment: `".*\\.add\\(.*\\.substring\\(.*\\)\\)"` does what you say.  But I don't think it's what you want.  Are there restrictions on what characters can appear in `any_var`, `anything` and `any`?

Comment: no restriction.. but your suggestion dont work

Comment: Can you show some code that indicates it not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
.+\.add\(.+\.substring\(.+\)\)
```